# Is it possible to ignore RiotParseException in Apache Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena

I'm parsing a file serialized in NQuads format which contains some annoying triples having some bad character (the Apache Jena parser throws a RiotParseException saying "Bad character encoding"). Is there any way (e.g. RDFParser setting) to ignore such exception and go ahead parsing the file?

Comment: "Bad character encoding" is caused by `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException`while doing UTF-8 to Java characters. There isn't a control to ignore it. There are several different UTF-8 problems that end up in this exception and for some the input is broken. Do you have examples of what sort of problem there is with the files? It is quite annoying but doing anything about this a can be a big performance hit on the "good" data case. If the error is systematic, then fixing the files with text handling tools is one approach. Do open a JIRA ticket (example data, which jena version etc).

Comment: The JIRA ticket opened had a lot more detail which really should be in your question here i.e. example code to reproduce, error message seen etc.  From that issue its clear that the problem is your data and you should investigate and fix your data (or the process that produces it) rather than trying to get Jena to ignore the problematic lines.

Comment: The data contains Unicode surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The data has a surrogate pair encoded into UTF-8 as two 3 byte sequences.

Bytes: ED A0 BD ED B4 94

This is illegal UTF-8 and Java enforces this https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-4

Bytes ED A0 BD ED B4 94 encodes the pair D83D DD14 which is codepoint 01F514. That codepoint can be directly encoded in UTF-8 as F0 9F 94 94.